# destroying a singleton object

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, oop

What is the best way to destroy a singleton object?

case A: Single threaded Environment
case B: Multi Threaded Environment

Sample snippets(if any) will be really helpful.

[EDIT] I don't have a specific use case I am just trying to understand that IF AT ALL the singleton has to be used how to destroy it correctly. As i understand, from the comments, there are 2 scenarios possible:
1. Destroy the singleton when no code is accessing it.(use smart pointers which will take care of destroying the object by itself using RAII)
2. Destroy a singleton when exiting the program irrespective of whether or not some code was holding on to the singleton. 
(explicitly destroy by deleting the instance just before main exits)

Comment: The _best_ way is usually to not have any singletons at all; then you don't have to destroy any singletons :-)

Comment: Deleting the source and header files should do the trick. Then come up with a design that doesn't use singletons.

Comment: For background on why "Singletons are Evil", read http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/scottdensmore/archive/2009/08/13/singletons-are-evil-part-2.aspx and its predecessor, which is linked from there.

Comment: Yes singletons are hard to use and cause problems if you are not carefull. But let us answer the question asked. If we want to discuss the merits of singletons that should be done it is own specific question.

Comment: @Martin: but a singleton can, pretty much by definition, not be explicitly destroyed (since that'd violate the invariant that a singleton is supposed to enforce, that *one* instance exits). So if you want to answer the specific question asked, the only correct answer is "you don't". And if we back off and start considering variations of singletons, then it only makes sense to ask if anything singleton-like is actually the right solution.

Comment: @Als: do you need to be able to explicitly destroy the singleton object, or do you just need to make sure that its destructor is called before the process exits?

Comment: @jalf: You interpreted the question differently to me then. To me the OP is asking how to make sure that a singleton object is correctly destructed (ie its destructor is correctly called and resources released). And how to make sure this processes is compiler implemented so that the user of the singelton does not need to do it manually.

Comment: Answering the other question if singleton is a good idea. For novices never. For Experts I can see it being used but there is rarely a need. And to do it correctly it can not be done in isolation. To make TDD work the singleton must be generated from a factory and the factory must be part of a plug-able interface (as you can see all non trivial to do correctly but it can be done).

Comment: @jalf, Martin - Thanks for commenting. I do agree, It is better to get rid of singletons rather than not but in certain cases one cant(some already existing legacy codes etc), so the q is if at all singletons MUST BE used, how to ensure you destroy them safely.

Answer (score 8):

Don't create it in the first place!

Seriously, I strongly recommend you reconsider your choice of singleton, especially in a multithreaded environment. Instead just create an instance in `main()` and pass it down the call hierarchy to where it is needed.

You can use something like `shared_ptr` to ensure that the object stays around until no-one needs it any more.

Comment: I do understand the pitfalls of using singleton and as most of you mentioned it should be avoided but if one do has to use singleton, then what are the options? wrap it up in a smart pointer which employs reference counting can be option too, I am looking for possible solutions or workarounds.

Comment: If you store the instance pointer in a smart pointer with static storage duration then it will be destroyed when the program exits.

Comment: @Als: why do you have to use a singleton? A singleton specifically *does not* allow you to destroy it (because then you no longer have a single instance)

Comment: @jalf Singleton does not mean there must be an instance, but at most one instance.

Answer (score 2):

Might be able to use [atexit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit) if you only care about cleaning up on successful shutdowns.

Answer (score 1):

In multi-threaded,

```
void Singleton::Destroy() 
{
  if (instance) { 
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      if (instance) { 
          delete instance;
          instance = 0x0;
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }
}
```

In single-threaded:

```
void Singleton::Destroy() 
{
  if (instance) { 
      delete instance;
      instance = 0x0;
  }
}
```

Comment: don't you mean 'if (instance)'?

Comment: @Arpan - Thanks! But the real problem i think is to ensure these destroy methods are called at the very end, when no resource needs the singleton anymore. I am trying to look for good solutions for that problem.

Comment: This can lead to multiple instances of your singleton on true multiprocessor systems with per-CPU cache or even depending on how compiler uses registers. You need to ensure that "instance" comes from main memory before checking for instance!=0. That's one of the functions of mutex on modern machines. This link (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) is mostly about Java, but it also works for C++.

Comment: Dont one use static MySingleton instance; return instance in these days?

Comment: @filipe Thanks, rectified that.

Comment: @Als There's a difference between when no code accesses the singleton and when the program ends. Not sure when you want the singleton to be destroyed. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The backlash against the last decade's overuse of Singletons seem to be in rude health, but they're not entirely evil or unjustified... programming is about compromises and being practical, and it's hard to generalise (generally ;-P).  By all means revisit the design and see if you can usefully get rid of them, but if not - so be it.

Anyway, if you want to understand the trade offs, you can't do better than start by reading Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design, which devotes a chapter to the alternatives for Singletons.  Basically, you're asking a silly question here because we don't know what operational constraints your singleton(s) have... what potential interactions, which resources they may need to use and whether they can be re-opened after being closed etc..  So, spit it out or settle for silly answers ;-P.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the question of if it is a good idea.
Which we should do in a separate question!

```
class S
{
    private:
        S() {}                // private constructor
        S(S const&);          // Undefined copy constructor
        S& operator(S const&) // Undefined assignment operator

    public:
        static S& getInstance()
        {
            /*
             * It is guaranteed to be built on first use
             * and correctly destroyed at the end of the application 
             */
            // Need guard for multi-threaded systems (but not on gcc)
            MULT_THREAD_GUARD;
            static S theOnlyInstance;
            return theOnlyInstance;
        }
};
```

The multi-thread initialization of the object is the only real problem. You can handle this two ways.

- You can either put a GUARD to make sure only one thread can enter the getInstance() method when you do multi-threaded builds (iff you use gcc this is not required as it plants the required code automatically to guarantee the object is only initialized once).
- The other technique is just to make sure the instance is initialized before any threads are created. To do this just call getInstance() in main. Mind you if you do this you may as well have a global variable as you destroy the main benefit of singletons over global variables (lazy initialization). Not that global variables are much better than singletons.

Example Guard

```
// Then in your platform agnostic header file
#ifndef MULTI_THREAD
#define MULT_THREAD_GUARD       /* Nothing needed in single threaded code */
#else
#if defined(__GNUC__) && ((__GNUC__ > 4) || ((__GNUC__ == 3 ) && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 1)))
#define MULT_THREAD_GUARD        /* Nothing required for GCC 3.2 onwards */
#elif defined(YOUR_COMPILERS_MACRO)
#define MULT_THREAD_GUARD        do { /* Put compiler lock code here */ } while (false)
#else
#error "ADD MULTI Thread GUARD for you compiler here"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a global, I prefer something like this:

```
class GlobalThing{ /* ... */ };

GlobalThing *global_thing = 0;

// ...

int main(){
  GlobalThing gt(/* ... */);
  global_thing = &gt;

  // create threads
  // ...
  // kill threads
}
```

This gives you:

1. An easily-identified lifetime for the global object.
2. Resource cleanup in the typical RAII manner.
3. The above points mean that it works in a multi-threaded environment without worrying about locks, etc., because no threads will exist before or after gt's lifetime. Well, in some environments, you can exit from main() and other threads will keep running, but that is a terrible way to architecture your program for a variety of reasons.

What you still have to worry about:

1. Initialization order of globals. But, this is unlike the [Static Initialization (and Destruction) Order Fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14), because this technique gives you the benefit of defining the globals' initialization and destruction order (if you define them all this way).
2. Something else, I'm sure.

Comment: One of the "something else" things would be if anything references the global pointer before main runs, eg: other global/static object initialization. That's not to say those are architecturally good either, but it's another case which does happen in real code...

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable way to change the Singleton into a "well behaved" (I don't believe I'm saying this) global variable.